# IISExpress.exe lags, PDB load problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, freeze

I was getting "Cannot find or open the PDB file" in the Output window when trying to debug an ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio 2013. The IDE would hang and the browser reported that it was waiting for localhost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is to rebuild the symbol cache. Be sure you have internet access--then, in the VS 2013 IDE, go to Tool | Options | Debugging | Symbols. Click "Empty Symbol Cache" and wait for that operation to complete. Then click "Load all symbols".

I hope this helps someone other than me.